# Where does the windows YouTube app save downloaded videos

Tags: video, download, youtube

Where does the Windows first party YouTube application save downloaded videos?

I am not talking about 3rd party solutions like VLC or some other program to download videos. I am taking about the official YouTube application for Windows. It can also be integrated into chromium browsers such as Brave.

The application requires a YouTube premium account to download videos

Answer (score 2):

I found it in

%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\https_[www.youtube.com_0.indexeddb.blob](http://www.youtube.com_0.indexeddb.blob)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB .....
its for chrome

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is saved in appdata/Local//User Data/default/IndexedDB

It does depend on the browser that you launch it from. If you launch it from a Windows shortcut, it might be inside appdata/Local/Google/.....

But if you have Brave browser open and launch it from inside Brave, then it might be in appdata/Local/Brave-Browser/.....

on my drive it is in "C:\Users\Zeno\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\IndexedDB"